# kubernetes unable to see the mounted folder contents

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube

I am trying to mount a local folder to a container. Every step went well without any errors but I still can't see the mounting.

I created a file `index.html` in `/home/azureuser/mnt/host`

my target is to mount local folder `host` to `/usr/share/nginx/html0` in the container.

### pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/azureuser/mnt/host"
```

### pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
```

### pod.yaml

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pod0
  labels:
    name: pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: mount
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc
  containers:
    - name: container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mount
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html0
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "128Mi"
          cpu: "250m"
```

upon on applying the three yaml in the order of the appearance. I shelled in to the `pod0` and `ls -al /usr/share/nginx/html0` it is `empty`. Also there is no symbolic link to `html0` to  `host`

Fyi the entire thing is happening in azure and it is minikube

```
kubectl get pod -o wide


NAME   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod0   1/1     Running   0          26h   172.17.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: You'll probably find it easier and more maintainable to create a custom image that has the content you need.  Especially if you have multiple hosts or you're using Azure's hosted Kubernetes, getting the same content on to every node is going to be an ongoing maintenance problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am still in a learning phase.

Comment: I tried your YAMLs on my GKE cluster and it's working without issue. Only things comes to my mind are: 1. Does your pod was deployed on the node where you have this folders `/home/azureuser/mnt/host`? If you have 3 nodes in cluster. You have create `/mnt/host` folder only on node 2, pod was deployed on node 1 or 3, it will be empty, as those folders wasn't on the node. Kubernetes will create folders on node 1 or 3, and it will be empty. In pod there will be no files as it was mounted on the node without this file you've created.

Comment: Second thing might permissions issues but I'd say the first option is issue here. Pod was scheduled on the node were you didnt created this folders and file. Please provide outputs of `kubectl get po -o wide` and name of the node where you created this folder `//home/azureuser/mnt/host` with files.

Comment: @PjoterS I am using minikube, so I dont have the luxury of multiple nodes, only one node. I pasted the output in my question. Since I am using only single machine both the folder and pod are in same machine. as far as permissions it has _rwxrwxrwx permissions

Comment: @Bhanu Tez which driver did you use to create Minikube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) it changed a bit my point of view.

#### Background

In [Using Minikube to Create a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/create-cluster/cluster-intro/) documentation you can find information, that

> Minikube is a lightweight Kubernetes implementation that creates a VM on your local machine and deploys a simple cluster containing only one node.

You mention, that you have created file

> I created a file index.html in /home/azureuser/mnt/host

I guess you have created it in your `Azure VM`, but as you are using `Minikube`, it should be created in `Minikube VM / Docker conainter` inside your `Azure VM`. It depends on driver you have used.

#### Tests

In my test I've used `docker driver` which creates `minikube container` where it stores it's data.

I have created VM and started `Minikube` with `docker driver`.

After creation, you are logged to your VM (I've already deployed your YAMLs).

```
user@minikube-new:~$ ls
minikube-linux-amd64  po.yaml  pv.yaml  pvc.yaml
user@minikube-new:~$ kubectl get po
NAME   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod0   1/1     Running   0          26s
```

After applying your YAMLs there should be `/home/azureuser/mnt/host` but it's not there.

```
user@minikube-new:~$ pwd
/home/user
```

Minikube during starting, **creates own docker container inside your VM**. You can enter it using `minikube ssh`.

```
$ minikube ssh
Last login: Thu Jan  7 09:16:46 2021 from 192.168.49.1
docker@minikube:~$ pwd 
/home/docker
docker@minikube:~$ cd ..
docker@minikube:/home$ ls
azureuser  docker
docker@minikube:/home$ cd azureuser/mnt/host/
docker@minikube:/home/azureuser/mnt/host$ touch index.html
touch: cannot touch 'index.html': Permission denied
```

I've changed permissions to `host` directory (`chmod`) and created file.

```
docker@minikube:/home/azureuser/mnt/host$ touch index.thml
docker@minikube:/home/azureuser/mnt/host$ echo "This is test message from Minikube MV" > index.html
docker@minikube:/home/azureuser/mnt/host$ cat index.thml 
This is test message from Minikube MV
docker@minikube:/home/azureuser/mnt/host$ exit
logout
user@minikube-new:~$
```

Now if you will check your pod `/usr/share/nginx/html0` folder, you will find `index.html`.

```
user@minikube-new:~$ kubectl exec -ti pod0 -- bash
root@pod0:/# cd /usr/share/nginx/html0
root@pod0:/usr/share/nginx/html0# ls
index.thml
root@pod0:/usr/share/nginx/html0# cat index.thml 
This is test message from Minikube MV
```

#### Conclusion

When you are creating `Minikube` you are automatically creates new `Minikube VM/container` inside your `Azure VM`. To enter `Minikube VM/container` you have to use `minikube ssh` command. If you will configure pod to use `Persistent Volume` with [HostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) it will be mount to `Minikube VM/container` not your `Azure VM`.

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod.